# Bluetooth ACTION_FOUND broadcastReceiver is not working

Tags: android, bluetooth

I'm trying to calculate bluetooth RSSI and found some example, but **broadcastReceiver** is not working. The code is this:

```
private final BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver(){

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        String action = intent.getAction();
        if(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action)) {
            int rssi = intent.getShortExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_RSSI,Short.MIN_VALUE);
            String name = intent.getStringExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_NAME);
            TextView rssi_msg = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
            rssi_msg.setText(rssi_msg.getText() + name + " => " + rssi + "dBm\n");
        }
    }
};
```

Registered through this:

```
registerReceiver(receiver, new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND));
```

And when button is clicked, BTAdapter.startDiscovery(); is working.
But nothing changed in textview.

Can you please have some advice for me?

Edit Again:
I changed my code little more and I'll show my whole code.

```
public class Blutooth extends Activity {

private BluetoothAdapter BTAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_blutooth);

    Button boton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    boton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v) {
            BTAdapter.startDiscovery();
        }
    });
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.blutooth, menu);
    return true;
  }
}
```

And receiver class is

```
public class TestReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String name = intent.getAction();
    String device = intent.getStringExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_NAME);
    String rssi_msg = Integer.toString(intent.getShortExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_RSSI,Short.MIN_VALUE));
    Toast.makeText(context, name, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  }

}
```

I'm trying to Toast `intent.getAction();` but nothing happened.
I think `BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND` is not broadcast.

edit again :
I'm using android 6.0 version.
And my whole manifest is this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.blutooth"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.bluetooth" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="23"
        android:targetSdkVersion="23" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".Blutooth"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <receiver android:name=".TestReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND">
            </action></intent-filter>
        </receiver> 
    </application>

</manifest>
```

I heard over 6.0 version need additional permission to use `ACTION_FOUND`.
So, I added `ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION` and `ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION`.
And I added `filter.addAction(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_NAME_CHANGED);` code in my activity.
`ACTION_NAME_CHANGED` is worked fine and I can get `BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_NAME`.
But `BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_RSSI,Short.MIN_VALUE` is not working.
It print default value -32768.
Still `BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND` is not working.

Comment: did you added receiver in manifest file also

Comment: Add more code, at least the whole class. Also, what does your `intent.getAction()` give you? Try using `Log.d` or `Toast`.

Comment: which android version do you use ? and also please add manifest also may be there is missing on permissions

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I finally found answer.
Android 6.0 needs additional permission, but Just adding uses-permission to Manifest is not working.
You have to check permission to user.
I write my code like this:

```
int permissionCheck = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(thisActivity, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION);

        BluetoothAdapter bluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
        if (!bluetoothAdapter.isEnabled())
          bluetoothAdapter.enable();
        leScanner = bluetoothAdapter.getBluetoothLeScanner();

        Button boton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        boton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View v) {
                leScanner.startScan(scanCallback);
            }
        });
```

This code show you permission pop up.
Thanks for many answers.

Answer (score 14):

You need a force request of `ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION` permission:

```
if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(activity, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(activity, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION}, PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);
}

BluetoothAdapter bluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
...
```

Found at https://www.sitepoint.com/requesting-runtime-permissions-in-android-m-and-n

Answer (score 5):

I got this working by turning on the location services on my device physically or you can do it programatically.

just turn it on before running your app and you can then see the list of devices.

The bluetooth API doesn't work if the location services are off.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to your post, once I requested the proper permissions, it worked.

### Kotlin

I've created a button with id `button`; when you click on it, you should see the list of devices in `Logcat`

AndroidManifest.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.picture_it" >
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

MainActivity.kt

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    companion object {
        const val REQUEST_ENABLE_BT = 42
//        val REQUEST_QUERY_DEVICES = 142
    }

    private var bluetoothAdapter: BluetoothAdapter? = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter()

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        if (bluetoothAdapter == null) {
            // Device doesn't support Bluetooth
            Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "Device doesn't support Bluetooth", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        } else if (bluetoothAdapter?.isEnabled == false) {
            val enableBtIntent = Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE)
            startActivityForResult(enableBtIntent, REQUEST_ENABLE_BT)
        }

        val permission1 = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH)
        val permission2 = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN)
        val permission3 = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION)
        val permission4 = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
        if (permission1 != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
            || permission2 != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
            || permission3 != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
            || permission4 != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                arrayOf(
                    Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH,
                    Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN,
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION,
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION),
                642)
        } else {
            Log.d("DISCOVERING-PERMISSIONS", "Permissions Granted")
        }

        val button = findViewById<Button>(R.id.button)
            button.setOnClickListener {
                if (bluetoothAdapter?.isDiscovering == true) {
                    bluetoothAdapter?.cancelDiscovery()
                }
                var filter = IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND)
                this.registerReceiver(receiver, filter)
                filter = IntentFilter(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_STARTED)
                this.registerReceiver(receiver, filter)
                filter = IntentFilter(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED)
                this.registerReceiver(receiver, filter)
                bluetoothAdapter?.startDiscovery()
        }
    }

    // Create a BroadcastReceiver for ACTION_FOUND.
    private val receiver = object : BroadcastReceiver() {
        override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent) {
            when (intent.action) {
                BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND -> {
                    // Discovery has found a device. Get the BluetoothDevice
                    // object and its info from the Intent.
                    val device: BluetoothDevice =
                        intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE)
                    val deviceName = device.name
                    val deviceHardwareAddress = device.address // MAC address
                    var msg = ""
                    if (deviceName.isNullOrBlank())
                    {
                        msg = deviceHardwareAddress
                    } else {
                        msg = "$deviceName $deviceHardwareAddress"
                    }
                    Log.d("DISCOVERING-DEVICE", msg)
                }
                BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_STARTED -> {
                    Log.d("DISCOVERING-STARTED", "isDiscovering")
                }
                BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED -> {
                    Log.d("DISCOVERING-FINISHED", "FinishedDiscovering")
                }
            }
        }
    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        unregisterReceiver(receiver)
        super.onDestroy()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use **XiaoMi** / **Redmi** / [MIUI](https://home.miui.com/), you must call **Loation-Related API** to fetch location permission:

For example:

```java
LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(locationManager.getAllProviders().get(0)); // The XiaoMi magic!!!
BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter().startDiscovery();
registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.d("Bluetooth", "It worked!");
    }
}, new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND));
```

Worked permission combination:

```xml
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```